# Class app.victory..... is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have the following class which I want to change a bit so as to make it more "object oriented" and easy to read.

```
   public class CreateLeague extends AppCompatActivity {
   ....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_league);

     createLeague(...);
 }
public void createLeague(final String leagueName, final String  username, final String password,final String start,final String end,final String openLeague) {
    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";



    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParams.put("league_name",leagueName);

    postParams.put("username",username);
    postParams.put("password",password);
    postParams.put("league_start",start);

    postParams.put("league_finish",end);
    postParams.put("open_league",openLeague);

    Response.Listener<JSONObject>  listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postParams);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_CREATE_LEAGUE, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    try {

                        if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){

                            Intent i = new Intent(CreateLeague.this, League.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

  }

 }
```

In other words I want to create the createLeague(...) to another class i.e. CreateLeagueClass and instantiate that object inside the onCreate() method of the above class. So here is what I do.

```
 public class CreateLeagueClass extends AppCompatActivity{
private void createLeague(final String leagueName, final String username, final String password,final String start,final String end,final String openLeague) {
    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";



    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParams.put("league_name",leagueName);

    postParams.put("username",username);
    postParams.put("password",password);
    postParams.put("league_start",start);

    postParams.put("league_finish",end);
    postParams.put("open_league",openLeague);

    Response.Listener<JSONObject>  listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postParams);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_CREATE_LEAGUE, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    try {

                        if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){

                            Intent i = new Intent(CreateLeague.this, League.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

  }
 }
```

The problem is that compiler is giving me an error in this line.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(CreateLeague.this, League.class);
```

of the CreateLeagueClass

The error is like this.

```
app....CreateLeague is not an enclosing class
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateLeague.this` is the current instance of CreateLeague. It only works inside that class,  When you move that code to another class, you have to pass that instance e.g. add a parameter `CreateLeague cL` to the Method `createLeague` and use `CreateLeague.this` when you call that method.

Comment: Thank you for that sir. I have ticked your answer as the correct one:).